# XSLT invalid token results in invalid XML document

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I am using an XSLT file to transform an XML file to another XML file and then creating this XML file locally. I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Token Text in state Start would result in an invalid XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write an XML fragment. '

The XSLT file was debugged in visual studios and it looks like it works correctly but I don't understand this error. What does this mean and how can it be fixed?

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<In xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="take.xsd">
  <Submit ID="1234">
    <Values>
      <Code>34</Code>
      <Source>27</Source>
    </Values>
    <Information>
      <Number>55</Number>
      <Date>2018-05-20</Date>
      <IsFile>1</IsFile>
      <Location></Location>
      <Files>
        <File>
          <Name>Red.pdf</Name>
          <Type>COLOR</Type>
        </File>
        <File>
          <Name>picture.pdf</Name>
          <Type>IMAGE</Type>
        </File>        
      </Files>
    </Information>
  </Submit>
</In>
```

My XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- identity template - copies all elements and its children and attributes -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/In">
    <!-- Remove the 'In' element -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Submit">
    <!-- Create the 'Q' element and its sub-elements -->
    <Q xmlns:tns="Q" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.xsd" Source="{Values/Source}" Notification="true">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Values" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Information" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Information/Files" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </Q>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Information">
    <!-- Create the 'Data' sub-element without all of its children -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Number"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Date"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="IsFile"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Location"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the C# code used to transform the file:

```
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(@"D:\\Main\XLSTFiles\Test.xslt");
        string xmlPath = @"D:\Documents\Test2.xml";
        using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(@"D:\Documents\NewFile.xml"))
        {
            xslt.Transform(xmlPath, w);
        }
```

Also, is there a way to produce the new XML file with proper indentation? It seems to create each node after the last one is closed and on the custom template it just appends each item one after another.

Comment: The `Transform` method has an overload `xslt.Transform(@"D:\Documents\Test2.xml", @"D:\Documents\NewFile.xml")` so use that instead of creating your own XmlWriter, that way XslCompiledTransform will internally create one with the right settings from your `xsl:output`. The message you get suggests your XSLT creates a fragment with several top level elements, if you want to use your own XmlWriter for such a result you need to use the proper XmlWriterSettings with `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen. For some reason switching the transform to the overloaded one you suggested even got rid of my fragment error without changing the XmlWriterSettings. Should that even occur this way? The file it's producing looks correct as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Michael Kay's excellent answer (as this was too long to write in comments), for your particular input XML the issue is with whitespace. In the template matching `/In` you do this...

```
<xsl:template match="/In">
  <!-- Remove the 'In' element -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But by selecting `node()` you are selecting the whitespace nodes before and after the child `Submit`, so you end up with a text node before your root `Q` element causing the error.

So, what you could do in this case, is simply strip out the whitespace from your XML by adding this to your XSLT

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```

Alternatively, you could also do this, to select only elements, as opposed other nodes (although this would omit comments and processing instructions)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
```

However, if you have multiple `Submit` elements in your XML, you then get multiple `Q` elements in your output, which will be a fragment, as there would be a single root element. If this is what you really intend, then you should make the following change to your C#...

```
 using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\tcase.BGT\Documents\NewFile.xml", xslt.OutputSettings ))
```

The default `ConformanceLevel` is ConformanceLevel.Auto, which I think allows fragments. Adding this will also solve your indentation problem, as it will use the settings in your `xsl:output`.

Comment: To my knowledge there will only be one submit element. If this is not the case then the XSLT would have to change right?

Comment: Yes. If there were multiple `submit` elements, and you wanted to output a well-formed XML (as opposed to a fragment), you would have to output a new root element that contained all the child `Q` elements.

Comment: A little detail: XML allows a well-formed document to contain whitespace characters before and after the outermost element node. But from this evidence it appears Microsoft's XMLWriter doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 3):

It's an amazingly unhelpful message, isn't it? But I think I can decipher it for you.

The XSLT processor is producing its output by writing events such as start-document, start-element, output-text to an XML Writer.

If you want to produce a well-formed XML document, then you can't have any text before the start of the first element. The message is saying that if the last thing you did is to issue start-document, then the next thing isn't allowed to be text, because the document would be ill-formed (it says invalid, but it means ill-formed).

Now, XSLT stylesheets are allowed to produce "well-formed fragments" rather than only being allowed to write "well-formed documents". Actually, the term used in the XML spec is "well-formed external general parsed entity", but that's a bit of a mouthful, so everyone calls them "fragments" because that's what DOM calls them, and there's no point using correct terminology in error messages if no-one understands it. The difference is that a fragment can contain multiple elements and text nodes at the top level, for example `this <b>really</b> is a <i>well-formed</i> fragment`. The problem is that the destination to which you write the XSLT output might not handle fragments, and in this particular case, the XML Writer can handle a fragment only if it's configured to do so.

I suspect you didn't actually intend to produce a fragment, and you need to fix your XSLT code so it outputs a well-formed document.